# What is the most efficient way to print all query results with column names?

Tags: java, resultset

I have a result set `ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();` I wrote a method to print query results as following

```
public void printResults(ResultSet rs) {
    // Getting column names
    int j = 1;
    while (true) {
        try {
    System.out.print(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(j)+"    ");
    j++;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Getting results
    while(rs.next()) {
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
            try {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+"  ");
        i++;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is :  is it a good idea to use `try && catch` ... I feel that it is not? Does it impact speed? What is a better way?

`Thank You`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get column number by

```
 ResultSetMetaData meta= rs.getMetaData();
 int columnNum=meta.getColumnCount();
```

Loop with this `columnNum` to get the result as well as column name.

```
for(int i=1;i<=columnNum;i++){
    System.out.print(meta.getColumnName(i)+" ");
}

//Get the data
while(rs.next){
  for(int i=1;i<=columnNum;i++){
    System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+" ");
  }
}
```